# Approach for ploting in VR with Python (using HTC Vive)?

Tags: python, plot, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I have recently purchased an [HTC Vive VR HMD](https://www.vive.com/us/) and was wondering if it could be used to visualize data being generated by Python?

Would there be any good approaches for plotting simple vertices/vectors in real-time using Python while visualizing them in the HMD (and possibly taking into account roomscale functionality)?

*I am a little bit familiar with [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) which uses OpenGL and I was really wondering/hoping it would be possible to tap into that library and implement the ability to see the PyQtGraph data in the HMDs and possibly walk around it using roomscale?*

Thank you very much for any input!!

Comment: As a followup, I have created a GitHub repository called [GravityVR](https://github.com/guiglass/GravityVR/) that demonstrates all of the above using OpenVR, Python and OpenGL.